# Prevent login when EmailConfirmed is false

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

The newest ASP.NET identity bits (2.0 beta) include the foundation for confirming user email addresses. The NuGet package "Microsoft Asp.Net Identity Samples" contains a sample showing this flow. But in that sample, even when `EmailConfirmed = false`, there is no different behavior in the user experience.

**How can I prevent users from being able to login when their email address is not yet confirmed?** I understand that I can have the users log in regardless and then perform the check on the `EmailConfirmed` field, but it seems like it would be much more efficient if I could prevent the user from successfully logging in at all when `EmailConfirmed == false`

Comment: Isn't there a `Login` action in `AccountController` where you can do that? I've not seen the newest sample though.

Comment: There is a login controller, but it looks like that's not where you specify an endpoint for authorization. I have this line in my code: TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token")

Comment: and it looks like from there the credentials are posted to /Token

Comment: Review the code at : http://thekevincode.com/2010/09/adding-email-confirmation-to-asp-net-mvc/

What it boils down to is, that by default when the account is created it is verified.  To allow for email confirmation, make the account unverified by default, send the confirmation email, create controller/view that validates the confirmation and marks the account as verified.

Comment: Yup, I've done all that successfully. But if you skip verification and go back to the login page, you can log in as the unverified user.

Comment: Can't you just use `WebSecurity.IsConfirmed(WebSecurity.CurrentUserName);` to check if they've been verified by email?

Comment: @X3074861X - WebSecurity.IsConfirmed is part of SimpleMembership, not ASP.NET Identity which this question is about.

Comment: Here is an article that shows how to setup email confirmation in ASP.NET Identity http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2013/10/adding-email-confirmation-to-aspnet.html .  This was written before the 2.0 alpha or beta and it shows that the new features added are not really required to implement email confirmation.

Comment: @KevinJunghans, one things is missing - in some case there is need to resend conformation token

Comment: @Arvis - I talk about resending the confirmation token in this post http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2013/04/retrieving-confirmation-token-in.html  Although this article is about using SimpleMembership the same logic would apply in ASP.NET Identity. The only difference is that it is easier to get access to the confirmation token since it is part of the ApplicationUser entity. If you look at the SimpleSecurity project in CodePlex [ http://simplesecurity.codeplex.com/ ] you can see an implementation in WebSecurity.GetConfirmationToken.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You need to add a few lines to the Login action (POST method) to verify that the user has confirmed their email.  The method you want to check is **UserManager.IsEmailConfirmed**.  Here is what your Login action will look like.

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);
            if (user == null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
            }
            //Add this to check if the email was confirmed.
            if (!await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user.Id))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "You need to confirm your email.");
                return View(model);
            }
            if (await UserManager.IsLockedOutAsync(user.Id))
            {
                return View("Lockout");
            }
            if (await UserManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, model.Password))
            {
                // Uncomment to enable lockout when password login fails
                //await UserManager.ResetAccessFailedCountAsync(user.Id);
                return await LoginCommon(user, model.RememberMe, returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                // Uncomment to enable lockout when password login fails
                //await UserManager.AccessFailedAsync(user.Id);
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

In this example I just return the user to the login view and display an error message. You could return them to another view that provides more details on the next steps to confirm their email, or even give them the option to resend the email confirmation.

Comment: Only tweak I would suggest would be to use the UserManager.IsEmailConfirmed instead of directly hitting the ApplicationUser.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. Does that work with OAuthAuthorization as well?

Comment: @HaoKung - What is the downside of calling ApplicationUser directly since we already have the user from checking if they entered a valid email?  Will calling UserManager.IsEmailConfirmed query the database again?

Comment: @BenjiFB - This should work fine with OAuth.  Users logging in with OAuth (external logins) go through different actions in the AccountController.  The Login action above is only for internal logins.

Comment: The downside is only in maintainability, if you swap out the EntityFramework implementation for something else (i.e. AzureTable storage) you will have to change that code, while if you go through the UserManager, that code uses the IUserEmailStore interface which other store implementations should have implemented.  The EF implementation of the method is just a simple get against the user instance which should be cached locally already.

Comment: @HaoKung - Thank you for the clarification. I have updated my answer to use your recommended method.

Comment: Great, you should probably use the Async version just like you do everywhere else for consistency

Comment: This flow would reveal the existence of an unverified or locked account to an attacker. Fringe case, but I thought I'd mention it. Would it be a good idea to put the confirmed/locked checks inside the final `if` clause?

Comment: @MattJenkins - You would have to weigh providing your users with useful information to know how to get access to their account with providing hackers with the same information. I think you are suggesting putting the checks in the final if so the message to the user is more generic.  All the hacker would have is that they have a valid username, which could be helpful for further exploits. I would say you would have to weigh the risk to your particular application versus user experience.  Another alternative is to add captcha so at least hackers could not automate this discovery.

Comment: Why is this not in the ASP.NET Identity 2.0 RTM? Will there be an update in the next release?

Answer (score 11):

in ApplicationOAuthProvider.cs

```
        public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
        {
            var userManager = context.OwinContext.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();

            ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);

            if (user == null)
            {
                context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
                return;
            }

            if (!user.EmailConfirmed)
            {
                context.SetError("invalid_grant", "Account pending approval.");
                return;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I am guessing this is also from the OWIN source? Can you provide references for this as it is not useful by itself.

Comment: This answer seems far simpler than the accepted answer - and checking the email verification immediately after checking the user exists seems like the best approach to me. Its obvious how to add any further checks as well.

Answer (score 10):

I just modified the case when the login could be successfull:

```
case SignInStatus.Success:
    if (!await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync((await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email)).Id))
    {
        Session.Abandon();
        AuthenticationManager.SignOut();
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "You need to confirm your email address");
        return View(model);
    }
    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
```

Comment: Avoid ALL CAPS in error messages... Shouting at users will not win them over! Good solution, although you may wish to add `Session.Abandon()` with the `SignOut()` (which is what the standard logout action does) :)

Comment: I find that adding ", you idiot!" to the message is just as effective as making it all caps. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Using the ASP.NET Identity 2.0 Samples.

### 1. Update the POST Login action in Account controller.

```
    //
    // POST: /Account/Login
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        // This doen't count login failures towards lockout only two factor authentication
        // To enable password failures to trigger lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
        var result = await SignInHelper.PasswordSignIn(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.EmailNotConfirmed:
                return View("EmailNotConfirmed");
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresTwoFactorAuthentication:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
        }
    }
```

### 2. Update the SignInStatus enum in IdentityConfig.cs.

```
public enum SignInStatus
{
    Success,
    EmailNotConfirmed,
    LockedOut,
    RequiresTwoFactorAuthentication,
    Failure
}
```

### 3. Update the PasswordSignIn method in IdentityConfig.cs.

```
    public async Task<SignInStatus> PasswordSignIn(string userName, string password, bool isPersistent, bool shouldLockout)
    {
        var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return SignInStatus.Failure;
        }
        if (!(await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user.Id)))
        {
            return SignInStatus.EmailNotConfirmed;
        }
        if (await UserManager.IsLockedOutAsync(user.Id))
        {
            return SignInStatus.LockedOut;
        }
        if (await UserManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, password))
        {
            return await SignInOrTwoFactor(user, isPersistent);
        }
        if (shouldLockout)
        {
            // If lockout is requested, increment access failed count which might lock out the user
            await UserManager.AccessFailedAsync(user.Id);
            if (await UserManager.IsLockedOutAsync(user.Id))
            {
                return SignInStatus.LockedOut;
            }
        }
        return SignInStatus.Failure;
    }
```

### 4. Add a new View "EmailNotConfirmed.cshtml".

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Email not confirmed";
}

<h2>You have not confirmed your email.</h2>

<p>Please click the link in the email we sent you to confirm your email.</p>

<p>todo: Add a "resend confirmation email" button here.</p>
```

Comment: SO is not cooperating with the code blocks. Mods, little help please. :)

Comment: Note: This solution requires using the source code of OWIN (otherwise you cannot modify files like `IdentityConfig.cs`). You cannot just consuming the libraries as per a scaffolded application.

Comment: If you make the numbered headings "headings" (using a single minus underneath) you can avoid SO messing up code formatting within lists :)

Comment: @GoneCoding Could you provide some info/references about how to use the source code of OWIN so that we can make these changes?