# Authorized sections of .net web app are accessible prior to confirmation email being clicked

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sendgrid

I'm using .net 4.5.2 and sendgrid. I've used the link below as a guide but rather than using sendgrid v2 i'm using sendgrid v3.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/features-api/account-confirmation-and-password-recovery-with-aspnet-identity

The email confirmation works with a link sent to the registered users email address. When that link is clicked the "Email Confirmation" field in AspNetUsers goes from false to true.

But when the user first submits the registration form - and prior to clicking the confirm email - they become logged into the system. Somehow _LoginPartial is being invoked because the users email address and logoff end up being at the top of the navbar.

So after thinking about it a bit the login action in ActionController is obviously being called just after registration but before email confirmation is clicked. That's not in the Microsoft doc i don't think.

But any advice to fix that would be great. I could check the AspNetUser table for EmailConfirmation == false. But is there a right place to do that?

I checked out this post [Prevent login when EmailConfirmed is false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22153921/prevent-login-when-emailconfirmed-is-false) and commented out the default login action code and replaced it with this below but it didn't seem to make a difference.

```
 if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);
                if (user == null)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                    return View(model);
                }
                //Add this to check if the email was confirmed.
                if (!await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user.Id))
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "You need to confirm your email.");
                    return View(model);
                }
                if (await UserManager.IsLockedOutAsync(user.Id))
                {
                    return View("Lockout");
                }
                if (await UserManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, model.Password))
                {
                    // Uncomment to enable lockout when password login fails
                    //await UserManager.ResetAccessFailedCountAsync(user.Id);
                    return await LoginCommon(user, model.RememberMe, returnUrl);
                }
                else
                {
                    // Uncomment to enable lockout when password login fails
                    //await UserManager.AccessFailedAsync(user.Id);
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                    return View(model);
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
```

The register action:

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new ApplicationUser {UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);

                    // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                    // Send an email with this link 

                    /*These bottom three lines were commented out */
                     string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                     var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                     await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\"></a>");
                    return RedirectToAction("ConfirmRegistration");
                }
                AddErrors(result);
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }
```

Login action:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Register` action, comment/remove the line:

```
await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);
```

That will disable the automatic sign in upon registering. Then, in your `Login` action, add the following code after the initial `ModelState.IsValid` check, to check if the user's email has been confirmed:

```
var user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
if (user != null && !await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user.Id))
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Please confirm your email address before signing in.");
    return View(model);
}
```