# asp.net core existing users confirm email, or allow to change email address

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm just wondering how to handle the following situation.

I currently have an asp.net mvc application, that I'm converting to asp.net core.
In the old asp.net mvc app, we never had email confirmations. I intend to force all existing users and new users to confirm emails in the new asp.net core version. I believe I can do this through the Login controller.

**Issue**
The issue I face is if people had fake email addresses or used someone else address, then they can never confirm that email.

**Proposed Solution**
So one way I thought of handling this, is when a user logs in, I give them an option to change their email and send the confirmation to this new email address?

Is that advisable? What are some good alternatives to this problem?

Comment: Yes, you can check on login whether the user is confirmed else you can tell them to confirm his/her email/account. and show button to send confirmation email.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating a resource filter to check if the user's email is confirmed and if not redirect to a view to handle that:

```
public class EmailConfirmedResourceFilter : IAsyncResourceFilter
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly IUrlHelperFactory _urlHelperFactory;

    public EmailConfirmedResourceFilter(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, IUrlHelperFactory urlHelperFactory)
    {
        _userManager = userManager ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(userManager));
        _urlHelperFactory = urlHelperFactory ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(urlHelperFactory));
    }

    public async Task OnResourceExecutionAsync(ResourceExecutingContext context, ResourceExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        var urlHelper = _urlHelperFactory.GetUrlHelper(context);
        var ignoreUrls = new[]
        {
            urlHelper.RouteUrl("ConfirmEmail"),
            urlHelper.RouteUrl("ChangeEmail")
        };
        if (!ignoreUrls.Contains(context.HttpContext.Request.Path.ToString())
            && context.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(context.HttpContext.User);
            if (user != null && !await _userManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user))
            {
                context.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult("ConfirmEmail");
            }
        }

        await next();
    }
}
```

Then, in `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddMvc(o => {
    o.Filters.Add<EmailConfirmedResourceFilter>();
});

services.AddScoped<EmailConfirmedResourceFilter>();
```

That seems like a lot of code, but it's pretty straight-forward. First, the filter calls out a few URLs that should be ignored. If we're on one of these pages, we don't want to redirect again, especially since that could potentially lead to an infinite redirect loop. We also check to see if the user is authenticated, because this is all a moot point if they're not even logged in.

Assuming those tests pass, then we pull out the user and check whether their email is confirmed. If not, we redirect to a place where they can do that. Otherwise, everything falls through to the `await next();` line which simply passes control to the next thing in the pipeline (i.e. we do nothing and let the request handling move on).

This will have the effect of forcing the user to the email confirmation page any time they attempt to navigate anywhere else if they are not yet confirmed. On said page, you can provide the option to change the email address (which will itself require a confirmation) or send an email to simply confirm the existing email address. Once the user confirms either way, they'll bypass this check and be able to move on to wherever else they want to go on the site.

Comment: thanks for that, sounds like a good solution. Only concern is performance of always checking this, every time you navigate? 

Is giving the user the option to change email advisable? any security issues?

Comment: Once the user is logged in, it's presumed they have the authority to change their email. It is possible someone could crack someone's account and change the email to take it over. If you're concerned about that you could build in a failsafe that also notifies the old email address about the change and gives them the ability via a link in the email to revert the change.

Comment: Cheers yeah that sounds logical, just for your interest another way to solve the issue of checking for email confirmation is to allow the user to login, then check if they have confirmed their email, if not sign them out and give them a message... as outlined here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22153921/prevent-login-when-emailconfirmed-is-false