# Require e-mail confirmed to login with OAuth2 on IdentityServer4

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, identityserver4

I am using `IdentityServer4` in my web API project for `OAuth2` authentication. However, I need to do a check to check if the user who wants to authenticate is with the confirmed email (basically, check if the `EmailConfirmed` is `true`).

After researching the topic, I found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22153921/prevent-login-when-emailconfirmed-is-false) that may satisfy my need - the second answer mentions an `ApplicationOAuthProvider.cs`, but I'm not sure how to use it in my Asp.Net Core 3.1 project.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to check that the EmailConfirmed claim is set to true/yes in the client's authorization policies. You can also use one of the event handlers to capture this and redirect the user to some other page if this claim is not set.